# How can I open the output of a backround process in terminal under Windows 10?

Tags: windows, terminal, process, windows-services

I have a program that I wrote: `main.exe` This software receives messages via HTTP and print it into the terminal (STDOUT). I've used [MSSN](https://nssm.cc/) to register this software as a service in order to start it automatically after boot.

(It's not suitable to use the startup folder in this case, because we're not able to login remotely. So, I needed a solution where the program starts immediately after boot without logging in.)

Now, it's running as a background process, but I have to check its output.

Is it possible to open a new terminal window for a running background process to see its actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to open a new terminal window for a running background process to see its actual output?

In your case, no, this is not possible. When you turn a program into a service, it is run by the SYSTEM account. Given you cannot login as SYSTEM, it is impossible to interact with its session. If you were able to do this, it would be a major security flaw anyway.

The only option you have to work around this, is to make the program output to a logfile that is saved somewhere so you can open the logfile.

Keep in mind that you will want to open the file, append to it, and close it again. Otherwise, the program keeps a writelock on the file, and you will not be able to see the content of the logfile.